# Number of solutions to multivariable polynomial modulo $p$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f \in \mathbb Z[x_1,...,x_n]$ be a polynomial of degree less than $n$, I want to show that the number of solutions to $f(x_1,...,x_n) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is divisible by p.

Really not sure how I should approach the problem, any hints or directions to get me started would be appreciated!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley–Warning_theorem . Hint if you don’t want the full proof: in small enough degree the monomials $X^{\alpha}$ of $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ satisfy $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p^n}{x^{\alpha}}=0$; then find a polynomial $g$ of small enough degree such that $g(x)=1$ if $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Hi @Mindlack Thanks for the comment, but I don't quite understand the Chevalley Warning theorem and the hint you suggested, the problem is intended to be proved in an elementary fashion for an undergraduate number theory class. I'm still not sure how to proceed.